# OpenCV VideoCapture: Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to capture a live youtube broadcast with an openCV.

Using pafy I get m3u8 playlist from youtube (didn't yet look into playlist updating), however segments on playlist are fragmented over multiple hosts, which seem to result in freeze on segment with different host than first one, and then an error like this:

```
Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host: r5---sn-x2pm-f5fs.googlevideo.com:-1 != r4---sn-x2pm-f5fs.googlevideo.com:-1
```

This seems to be ffmpeg problem, but maybe there is some workaround I missed?

My code:

```
mPafy = pafy.new('VQOzkTEPCMw')
mStream = mPafy.getbest(preftype="mp4")

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(mStream.url)
while(True):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('yt', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT:

I bypassed VideoCapture and called ffmpeg directly, it's a bit better, there are still freezes whenever segment is on different host, but only for ~1 second. and segment is not lost, ffmpeg opens new connection and grabs it, it just takes time to open connection.

Tbf I have no idea where should I go from this. One way would be to deal with m3u8 playlist manually and feed ffmpeg stream of data to decode, but it feels like overkill. Anyway here's my current code:

```
import pafy
from cv2 import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np

mPafy = pafy.new('VQOzkTEPCMw')
mStream = mPafy.getbest(preftype='mp4')
frameSize = 3*mStream.dimensions[0]*mStream.dimensions[1]

pipe = sp.Popen(['./ffmpeg.exe', '-i', mStream.url, '-f', 'image2pipe', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
                 '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-'],
                stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=frameSize)
while(True):
    raw = pipe.stdout.read(frameSize)
    frame = np.fromstring(raw, dtype='uint8').reshape(
        mStream.dimensions[1], mStream.dimensions[0], 3)
    cv2.imshow('yt', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(16) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
pipe.terminate()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

For `ffmpeg` you can use `-http_persistent 0` to avoid this error.

Comment: `-http_persistent` need to be put before `-i` option or it will not work.